# auto-complete not working after taking input suggestions from php file

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, sql

What I want to achieve?
1. a list of suggestions (may have same label, but different desc)
2. on selecting one item from that from that list of suggestions, another input field's input should change to the corresponding desc of the selected item.

When I was initializing var projects directly in javascript, it was working. But when I changed it to take list of suggestions from a php file, only it's selection part is working and filtering results on the basis of partial input stopped working.

For screenshots, please visit this link on github :-
https://github.com/rohitdeepu17/BusinessManagement/tree/master/ProjectCode/TestingFiles/Screenshots

and the code files are as below:-
test_jquery_autocomplete.php

```
     <?php
          include 'session_check_common.php';
          include 'connect_my_sql_db.php';
     ?>

     <!doctype html>
     <html lang = "en">
     <head>
           <meta charset = "utf-8">
           <title>jQuery UI Autocomplete functionality</title>
           <link href = "https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/themes/ui-lightness/jquery-ui.css"
     rel = "stylesheet">
           <script src = "https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
           <script src = "https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>

  <style>
     #project-label {
        display: block;
        font-weight: bold;
        margin-bottom: 1em;
     }
     #project-description {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
     }
  </style>

  <!-- Javascript -->
  <script>
     $(function() {
        /*var projects = [
           {
              "label": "Java",
              "desc": "write once run anywhere"
           },
           {
              "label": "Java",
              "desc": "rohit here"
           },
           {
              "label": "jQuery UI",
              "desc": "the official user interface library for jQuery"
           },
           {
              "label": "Twitter Bootstrap",
              "desc": "popular front end frameworks "
           }
        ];*/
        $( "#project" ).autocomplete({
           minLength: 0,
           //source: projects,
           source: "get_customers.php",
           focus: function( event, ui ) {
              $( "#project" ).val( ui.item.label );
                 return false;
           },
           select: function( event, ui ) {
              $( "#project" ).val( ui.item.label );
              $( "#project-description" ).html( ui.item.desc );
              $( "#project-description" ).val( ui.item.desc );
              return false;
           }
        })

        .data( "ui-autocomplete" )._renderItem = function( ul, item ) {
           return $( "<li>" )
           .append( "<a>" + item.label + "<br>" + item.desc + "</a>" )
           .appendTo( ul );
        };
     });
  </script>
 </head>

  <body>
   <form action="test_autocomplete.php" class="subform" method="post">
  <div id = "project-label">Select a project (type "a" for a start):</div>
  <input id = "project">
  <input id = "project-description" name="projectdescription">

  <button type="submit">SUBMIT</button>
</form>
```

and get_customers.php

```
  <?php 
    include 'connect_my_sql_db.php';
    $sql="select cust_id, cust_name, father_name from customer"; 
    $cust_name = array();
    $father_name = array();
    $result=mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
    while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) 
    { 
      $title=$row['cust_name']; 
      $url=$row['father_name']; 
      $posts[] = array('label'=> $title, 'desc'=> $url);
    } 
    echo json_encode($posts);
   ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to filter your result on the basis of `cust_name` like,

```
$sql="SELECT cust_id, cust_name, father_name FROM customer 
        WHERE cust_name LIKE '%".$_REQUEST['term']."%'";
```

Also, you need to initialise `$posts` variable, otherwise it will cause error of undefined and your Autocomplete response will fails,

```
// add below line before while loop
$posts = array();
while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
  ....
```

Comment: I am new to JQuery. I don't know how to pass 'term' to my php file. Can you please help me out?

Comment: You don't need to pass term, Read more here https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#remote

Comment: @Roshan Kumar why is it not working if I change

         $posts[] = array('label'=> $title, 'desc'=> $url); 

to:-
         $posts[] = array('cust_name'=> $title, 'father_name'=> $url);

and then retrieving accordingly

Comment: Don't change them, otherwise you need to change it in JS code also. Refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11375922/jquery-autocomplete-without-using-label-value-id

Comment: What if I want to show suggestions like "customer_name father_name". But search criteria should be customer_name only. Just to let the user make a selection accordingly, rather than just checking again and again to see which one he wanted to select.

Comment: You can do it by changing renderItem only in JS like `return $( "<li>" )
           .append( "<a>" + item.customer_name + ", S/O" + item.father_name + "</a>" )
           .appendTo( ul );
`